# How to increase the badge number automatically when sending push notifications from AWS SNS?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon Web Services to send “Push Notifications” to an IOS Application. How to increment the badge number automatically in swift 2?

I am using the following code in AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    let notificationSettings : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0        
    return true
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993903/how-to-update-the-badge-number-in-ios-push-notification

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just say "increment the badge count".

The way it works is that you have to tell the badge count in each push notification that you send explicitly.